# Not able to get value from Async function which returns value by calling asyncStorage function

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

In _retrieveSelectedBusNumber i'm returning value of selectedBusNumber by calling asyncStorage. 
In TaskManager.defineTask I want to retrieve the selectedBusNumber value, but currently I'm receiving a promise.

```
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("selectedBusNumber").then(
      data => data
    );
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value, "value");
      return value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
  }
};


TaskManager.defineTask(FETCH_LOCATION_TASK, ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error in fetch location from fetch_location_task");
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const location = data;
    console.log(location);
    var database = firebase.database();
    let selectedBusNumber = _retrieveSelectedBusNumber().then(data => data);

    //below console returns ----> Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null} "_retrieveSelectedBusNumber()" <----

    console.log(selectedBusNumber, "_retrieveSelectedBusNumber()");
    const busNumber = async () =>
      await _retrieveSelectedBusNumber().then(data => data);
//below console returns ---> ƒ busNumber() <----    
console.log(busNumber, "busnumber");
  }
});
```

I expect to retrieve selectedBusNumber value using _retrieveSelectedBusNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot to be improved in this code, but the main problem is the line below:

```
    let selectedBusNumber = _retrieveSelectedBusNumber().then(data => data);
```

You need to `await` the data from the promise:

```
    let selectedBusNumber = await _retrieveSelectedBusNumber();
```

For that to work you also need to add an `async` in front of your `defineTask` callback. 
Also `.then(data => data)` is without any effect, you can remove it.

Comment: I've also tried this way like this -
 ```const busNumber = async () =>
      await _retrieveSelectedBusNumber().then(data => data);
//below console returns ---> ƒ busNumber() <----    
console.log(busNumber, "busnumber");```
Also tried removing .then but again it returns a function as mention in the comment.

Comment: Do not add `async () => ` in front of your call to `_retrieveSelectedBusNumber`. That is wrapping the value you `await` in yet another promise. Add `async` in front of your `defineTask` callback. I would recommend reading about promises in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your function to fetch from `AsyncStorage` should look like this

```
 async GetLocalStorage(key){
        try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("selectedBusNumber");
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value, "value");
      return value;
    }
  } catch (error) {
     console.log("error");
     console.log(error);
      }
     };
    }
```

Comment: You are right with the observation that the function header was missing in his example code - but that does not solve the problem, see other response.